# Issue with a BorderLayout and imaging

Tags: gwt, gxt

Could you please take a look at the code below to suggest how to correct it to make it works? I tried to use different browsers but result is the same: nothing happens. There is just a blank screen:

```
public class GXTApp implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {

        Viewport viewPort = new Viewport();

        final BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
        viewPort.setLayout(borderLayout);

        BorderLayoutData westData = new BorderLayoutData(Style.LayoutRegion.WEST, 200, 150, 300);
        westData.setCollapsible(true);
        westData.setSplit(true);

        BorderLayoutData centerData = new BorderLayoutData(Style.LayoutRegion.CENTER);
        centerData.setCollapsible(false);

        ContentPanel navPanel = new ContentPanel();
        ContentPanel mainPanel = new ContentPanel();
        viewPort.add(navPanel, westData);
        viewPort.add(mainPanel, centerData);

        RootPanel.get().add(viewPort);
    }
}
```

Thank you for ideas how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in GXT 3

```
        Viewport viewPort = new Viewport();

        final BorderLayoutContainer borderLayout = new BorderLayoutContainer();
        viewPort.add(borderLayout);

        BorderLayoutData westData = new BorderLayoutData(300);
        westData.setCollapsible(true);
        westData.setSplit(true);

        BorderLayoutData centerData = new BorderLayoutData();
        centerData.setCollapsible(false);

        ContentPanel navPanel = new ContentPanel();
        ContentPanel mainPanel = new ContentPanel();
        borderLayout.setWestWidget(navPanel,westData);
        borderLayout.setCenterWidget(mainPanel);

        RootPanel.get().add(viewPort);
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! But I work with GXT 2.2.5 (I've joint a development team recently and this framework version is used in our project) and it differs from 3.x. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work for me.